How to increase the maximum length of SpEL expressions in spring boot 3.3.0?
When I upgraded the spring boot version to 3.3.0, I started getting the error below. How can I increase the max length of SpEL expression?
Error:
<SpelEvaluationException> EL1079E: SpEL expression is too long, exceeding the threshold of '10,000' characters 

Java Code:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Value("#{${mySpringBoot.map}}")
    private Map<String, String> map;
}


According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/evaluation.html#expressions-parser-configuration you can use spring.context.expression.maxLength to configure what you want.
